# datetimepicker with editable datatable showing alert after update

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker, datatables, datetimepicker

I'm having problem on editing of a datatable with datetimepicker. As it says in the documents  of the plugin that, the php script must return the same value that is sending to the script while I'm updating value of a cell of the datatable.
For example:
If I'm changing value of the column "Test" then the return of the script must be "Test".
In this way my other column is working but datetimepicker column isn't.

```
$('#exampñe').dataTable({
            sPaginationType: "full_numbers",
            aoColumns: [
                {
                    sName: "id"
                },
                {
                    sName: "name"
                },
                {
                    sName: "matchdate",
                    sClass: "datetimepicker"
                },
                {
                    sName: "Action"
                }
            ]
        })
                .makeEditable({
                    "sAddURL": "<URL>",
                    "sDeleteURL": "<URL>",
                    "sAddDeleteToolbarSelector": ".dataTables_length",
                    "oEditableSettings": {event: 'click', onblur: 'submit'},
                    "sUpdateURL": "<URL>",
                    aoColumns: [
                        null,
                        {},
                        {
                            tooltip: 'Click to change date and time',
                            loadtext: 'loading...',
                            type: "datetimepicker",
                            datetimepicker: {
                                format: 'Y-m-d H:i:00',
                                changeMonth: true,
                                changeYear: true,
                                showHour: true,
                                showMinute: true,
                                step: 30
                            }
                        }]
                });
```

In PHP script i recieve the value as $_POST['value']. and also doing echo of this same value without any change.
When I'm changing name or other column that contains dropdown list it works fine. But datetimepicker is not working. I use this editable plugins to edit data in the database. all this column is updating in the database including datetimepicker. But it's not updating the datatable when it finishes editing the cell.
please help me out.
If I can't make it understand the question please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: may be the issue with the format of the datetime etc ?

Comment: passing the value as a string and returning as a string. -> no success
Also I tried with passing the value as a string and convert it to date and return as date -> No succes